# Eliminar registro en base de datos al confirmar sweetalert PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, delete

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente.

Actualmente estoy creando algunas opciones para que los usuarios de mi sitio puedan modificar o eliminar unos anuncios previamente creados por ellos. Esto lo hago mediante datos alojados en una base.

Mi problema es que no logro hacer que la función para eliminar el registro se aplique correctamente.

Actualmente lo que sucede es que al ingresar el usuario a la sección del sitio en la cual puede eliminar estos anuncios se eliminan automáticamente todos los anuncios que este usuario tenga registrados hasta el momento, sin realizar ninguna acción más que el ingreso a la propia página. Esto me supone un gran error puesto que en realidad necesito que el usuario decida justamente eliminar sus propios anuncios y que sea uno por uno, no que todos sean eliminados bajo la misma ejecución.

Adjunto el código correspondiente.

***EDIT: actualicé el código en base a las recomendaciones de los usuarios y ahora tengo lo siguiente. Resulta que así no logro hacer que funcione, pero si declaro !isset se ejecuta el código y se eliminan los anuncios simplemente apretando F5. No entiendo cual es el problema ahora:***

**Código `PHP` y `Javascript` utilizado para mostrar los anuncios y dar al usuario la opción de eliminarlos.**

```
        <?php
    $CantShow=10;
        $compag = (int)(!isset($_GET['publishpShow'])) ? 1 : $_GET['publishpShow'];
        $TotalReg = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
        $totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
        $TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr/$CantShow);
        $IncNum = (($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):0;
        $consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantShow)." , ".$CantShow);
        //$consultA = mysqli_query($conexion, $consult);
    ?>
    <div class="publishmShow">
        <?php
        while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
                $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $lista['id']);
                $usuariob = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$userid'");
                $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
        ?>
                <div class="publishContainer">
                    <div class="publish">
                        <div class="publishCInfo">
                            <?php $date = $lista['fecha']; ?>
                            <p class="publishCDate">Publicado el <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))?> a las <?php echo date('G:i', strtotime($date))?></p> 
                            <div class="publishCZone"><p class="publishCProv">En <?php echo $lista['provincia']?></p> <p class="publishCLoc"><?php echo $lista['localidad']?></p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDisplay">
                            <div class="publishCOffer">
                                <p class="publishCQuantity"><?php echo $lista['cantidad']?></p>
                                <p class="publishCCurrency"><?php echo $lista['moneda']?></p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="publishCFee">Fee <?php echo $lista['comision']?>%</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDetails">
                            <p class="publishCOperation"><?php echo $lista['operacion']?></p>
                            <div class="publishCMethod">
                                <p class="publishCMethodAccepted">Acepta:</p><p class="publishCP2P"><?php echo $lista['p2p']?></p><p class="publishCF2F"><?php echo $lista['f2f']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPModify" id="modifyButton">
                            <p>Modificar</p><i class="fa fa-magic" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div type="submit" class="publishPDelete">
                            <input type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" class="deleteButton" value="Eliminar" onclick="confirm();"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section class= "seccion2 contenedor">
  <div class="userprofilebackto">
    <a href="market.php">Volver al Mercado</a>
  </div>
</section>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm(){
        swal({
            title: '¡Cuidado!',
            text: '¿Estás seguro de querer eliminar tu anuncio?',
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons:{
                cancel: "No, volver",
                confirm: "Sí, eliminar",
            },
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            <?php
            $delcons = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($delcons)){
                $POST['id_pub'] = $row['id_pub'];              
                if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                    $del = mysqli_query($conexion, "DELETE FROM anuncios WHERE id_pub = {$row['id_pub']}");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            ?>
            swal('¡Anuncio eliminado!','¿Querés publicar uno nuevo?','success', {button: 'Continuar'});
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Adjunto también una imagen de como se compone la base de datos en la que se alojan los anuncios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito entender cual es el defecto que provoca que no pueda llevar adelante mi función de eliminar un registro de la manera en que lo preciso.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes el `script` dentro del ciclo `while`, por esa razón los elimina todos. Cada vez que muestra un registro, automáticamente lo está eliminando. Debes pasar el `script` al final del archivo _o en un archivo independiente_  y solo ejecutarlo al pulsar un botón con id `deleteButton`

Comment: Moví el script al final del archivo y el error me sigue apareciendo del mismo modo. Simplemente entro a la página y se eliminan todos los anuncios, sin darme tiempo ni siquiera a que ejecute la opción de eliminarlo mediante el botón. No logro entender cual es el problema.

Comment: Ya edité la publicación con el código actualizado y el 'avance' que logré hasta aquí.

Comment: Es que eso es lo que hace tu código, borrar todas las filas. Aquí `SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id'` supongo que tú estás trayendo todos los anuncios del usuario, para luego borrarlas una por una dentro del bucle con esta consulta: `DELETE FROM anuncios WHERE id_pub = {$row['id_pub']}`. Tú no necesitas traer todos los anuncios del usuario, sino sólo el que quieres borrar, capturarando el id de ese anuncio  (y eventualmente también el id el usuario) y lanzar una consulta DELETE basada en esos dos datos. También, te recomendaría que uses Ajax para esto.

Comment: Entiendo. Pero tienes idea como podria capturar el id_pub? Es lo que principalmente afecta mi código, no entiendo como traerlo a mi consulta de DELETE

Comment: Supogo que tienes un elemento que contiene ese dato, desde él puedes obtener el id del anuncio que se ha presionado y ejecutar el `DELETE`, por eso te recomendé que usaras Ajax porque es sumamente fácil hacerlo de este modo, y además no necesitas recargar la página.

Comment: Entiendo pero nunca utilicé Ajax en mi proyecto y realmente no sé como implementarlo correctamente, ademas creo que para utilizarlo debería crear ciertos controladores y demás, verdad?